# Edit mode viewport looks exactly the same as object mode

Tags: edit-mode

For some reason, when I switch from Edit mode to Object mode the images look exactly the same(see images below) how can I get back to the normal Edit Mode where I can see vertices/faces/etc.?

Edit Mode:
[image: Picture of Edit Mode]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have viewoprt overlays turned off. Click on the icon so that it's blue and white and they will reappear!

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome!